# jQuery Date picker not working in visual studio 2010

Tags: jquery, visual-studio-2010, jquery-ui-datepicker

[image]

Hi all I have done a work regarding `date picker` in `visual studio 2010` which is working fine in `VS2005` and `VS2008`..

my sample design is

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default2.aspx.cs" Inherits="Default2" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> <head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.datepick.js"></script>

    <style type="text/css">
        @import "css/jquery.datepick.css";
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('<%= txtHiredate.ClientID %>').datepick({ showOnFocus: false, showTrigger: '#calImg' });
        });
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('<%= txtDateofBirth.ClientID %>').datepick({ showOnFocus: false, showTrigger: '#Img1' });
        });
    </script> </head> <body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" ValidationGroup="personal"
        Style="left: 459px; position: absolute; top: 171px" />
                <asp:Label ID="lblDate" runat="Server" Text="HireDate" style="left: 321px; position: absolute; top: 98px"></asp:Label>

    <asp:Label style="LEFT: 310px; POSITION: absolute; TOP: 133px" id="Label1" runat="Server" Text="DateofBirth"></asp:Label>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtHiredate" runat="server" ValidationGroup="personal" Style="left: 397px;
                    position: absolute; top: 96px" />


                <div style="display: none;">
                    <img id="calImg" src="images/calendar.gif" alt="Popup" class="trigger" style="left: 564px;
                        position: absolute; top: 101px" />
                </div>

    <asp:TextBox ID="txtDateofBirth" runat="server" ValidationGroup="personal" Style="left: 398px;
        position: absolute; top: 131px" />
    <asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" runat="server" ClientValidationFunction="validatehiredate"
        ControlToValidate="txtDateofBirth" ValidationGroup="personal" Display="Dynamic"
        Style="left: 596px; position: absolute; top: 132px">can not hire guy less than 18 yrs</asp:CustomValidator>
    <div style="display: none;">
        <img id="Img1" src="images/calendar.gif" alt="Popup" class="trigger" style="left: 568px;
            position: absolute; top: 136px" />
    </div>
    </form> </body> </html>
```

But when I open `vs2005` solution in `Vs2010` a message regarding `web.config` raises if I click on ok and run this is working fine. But if I create a new solution and working on this it is not showing the corresponding images.. Can any one help me..

Comment: What is the "message regarding web.config"?

Comment: The message that comes when we are trying to open the lower version in higher version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try as per below

```
 $('<%= txtHiredate.ClientID %>')
 $('<%= txtDateofBirth.ClientID %>')
```

to

```
$('#<%= txtHiredate.ClientID %>')
$('#<%= txtDateofBirth.ClientID %>')
```